# How to add an empty attribute in rails form_for tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

To make foundation validations work, I have to add the 'data-abide' attribute to form tag like this :

```
<form data-abide>
```

How can I do this using the form_for tag in rails?

The full rails code :

```
<%= form_for @member, html: {class: "custom"} do |f| %>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try using

```
<% form_for @your_object, :html => {:data => {:abide => 'your-data-abide'}} do |f|%>
```

Comment: It will create '<form data-abide="your-data-abide >"' but I need <form data-abide>

Comment: I guess if you have to put any attribute in the form, then you need to add a value to it.

Comment: I don't understand how this is the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: Me too... can't understand how empty this is as content.

Answer (score 1):

In rails form_for syntax, you can do the following:

```
:html => {"data-abide" => ''}
```

I'm using abide as well with form helpers and it works great this way.

Answer (score 1):

I use it in my form_for helpers like the following example:

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { :"data-abide" => "" } do |f| %>
```

This will produce the following html, and Abide will work:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" data-abide="" id="new_user" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `<%= form_tag '', 'data-abide' => '' %>...<% end %>` or `<%= tag :form, 'data-abide' => '' do %><% end %>`

Is there a reason to use rails helpers for it? Wouldn't it be easier to just use `<form data-abide>`?

Comment: Im creating the form for a model. To add data to the model.

Comment: 'data-abide' => '' won't work :( Out side html:, it won't generate anything. Inside the html: (<%= form_for @member, html: {class: "custom", 'data-abide' => ''}, 'data-abide' => '' do |f| %>), it will generate data-abide=""

Answer (score 0):

Add this helper method into application helper

```
def tag_options(options, escape = true)
      unless options.blank?
        attrs = []
        options.each_pair do |key, value|
          if key.to_s == 'data' && value.is_a?(Hash)
            value.each do |k, v|
              unless v.is_a?(String) || v.is_a?(Symbol) || v.is_a?(BigDecimal)
                v = v.to_json
              end
              v = ERB::Util.html_escape(v) if escape
              attrs << %(data-#{k.to_s.dasherize}="#{v}")
            end
          elsif !value.nil?
            final_value = value.is_a?(Array) ? value.join(" ") : value
            final_value = ERB::Util.html_escape(final_value) if escape
            attrs << %(#{key}="#{final_value}")
          end
        end
        " #{attrs.sort * ' '}".html_safe unless attrs.empty?
      end
    end
```

then use <%= form_for(@member, :data => {'abide' => ''}) do |f| %>, which will produce html

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/members" class="new_member" data-abide="" id="new_member" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Josh Lehmans answer helped me out. Here's a full working example of a form.

```
<%= form_for @customer, html: {"data-abide" => ''} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Your name", :required => '' %>
    <%= content_tag(:small, "This field is required", class: "error") %>
<% end %>
```